# Simple program but can't get it right

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem**

> Turtles live long (and prosper). Turtles on the island Zanzibar are
>   even immortal. Furthermore, they are asexual, and every year they give
>   birth to at most one child. Apart from that, they do nothing. They
>   never leave their tropical paradise.
>
> Zanzi Bar, the first turtle on Zanzibar, has one further activity: it
>   keeps track of the number of turtles on the island. Every New Year’s
>   Day it counts the turtles, and writes the total number in a small
>   booklet. After many years this booklet contains a non-decreasing
>   sequence of integers, starting with one or more ones. (After emerging
>   from its egg on Zanzibar’s beautiful beach, it took Zanzi some time to
>   start a family on its own.)
>
> One day Zanzi realizes that it could also be the case that turtles
>   from abroad come to Zanzibar, by boat or plane. Now it wonders how
>   many of the inhabitants were not born on Zanzibar. Unfortunately, it
>   can only derive a lower bound from the sequence in the booklet.
>   Indeed, if the number of turtles in a year is more than twice as big
>   as the year before, the difference must be fully explained by import.
>
> As soon as Zanzibar has 1000000 turtles, the island is totally covered
>   with turtles, and both reproduction and import come to a halt. Please
>   help Zanzi! Write a program that computes the lower bound of import
>   turtles, given a sequence, as described above.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input starts with a line containing an integer T(1≤T≤13), the
>   number of test cases. Then for each test case:
>
> One line containing a sequence of space-separated, positive integers
>   (≤1000000), non-decreasing, starting with one or more ones. For
>   convenience, a single space and a 0 are appended to the end of the
>   sequence.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, output a line containing a single integer: the
>   lower bound for the number of turtles not born on Zanzibar.

[See question and sample input and output here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/zanzibar)

**My approach**

```
    public Zanzibar() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterations = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        int previous = -1;
        int current = -1;
        int lower = 0;

        while (true) {

            if (current != -1)
                previous = current;

            current = scan.nextInt();

            if (current == 0)
                break;

            if (current > 2 * previous && previous != -1)
                lower += current - previous;
        }
        System.out.println(lower);
    }
}
```

I think I am understanding the problem wrong. Am I supposed to keep adding to the lower bound or should I find the biggest difference between two years? Also I don't understand how input 1 100 0 produces output 98 (from the link). Shouldn't it be 99?

Comment: Erm, can you please give a problem statement without telling us a story about the world and everything?

Comment: @ThomasWeller It's a challenge OP is trying to solve and understanding this challenge is part of the problem here, so he could not take it off from the question. Maybe his question itself is off-topic here?

Comment: Also: most part seems to be quoted from the linked website. You might want to indicate that by using citation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the problem setter wants us to understand:

The initial `1` for every test case means that the initial population on the island is always `1`

So for an input like `1 1 1 0`, it means that:

The initial population is `1`. Then at the start of the 2nd year, the population is still `1`. At the start of the 3rd year, the population is still `1`.

As for your doubt about the input: `1 28 0`, it means that:

At the start of the 2nd year, the population is `28`, whereas the maximum that could have been is `2`, as the only turtle could have given birth to one more turtle at max. So, it means that clearly, at least `(28-2) = 26` turtles migrated!!!

Hope it helps...

**Edit:** This is the algorithm:

For every line of test case do the following:

- Set `initial` to `1`, `migrated` to `0`
- Start reading from the second number in the line, until we encounter a `0`:

  1. If the `current` number is greater than `2*initial`: `migrated = migrated + (current - 2*initial)`
  2. Else: do nothing
  3. Set `initial` to `current`
- Print `migrated`

**Edit-2:**

Here is the JAVA implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterations = scan.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    int len,x;
    int j,initial;
    long migrated;
    int arr[] = new int[1000005];
    while(i<iterations)
    {
      len = 0;
      while(true)
      {
        x = scan.nextInt();
        if(x==0)
          break;
        arr[len++] = x;
      }
      initial = arr[0];
      migrated = 0;
      j = 1;
      while(j<len)
      {
        if(arr[j]-(2*initial)>0)
        {
          migrated += arr[j]-(2*initial);
        }
        initial = arr[j];
        j++;
      }
      System.out.println(migrated);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Input:**

```
3
1 100 0
1 1 1 2 2 4 8 8 9 0
1 28 72 0
```

**Output:**

```
98
0
42
```